# How to get only the first line matching the regex in Java using Pattern matcher?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a list of football club names in a text file with one name per line.

```
Arsenal
Manchester United
Chelsea
Liverpool
...
...
Manchester City
Real Madrid
```

Suppose I need to find lines starting with "Manchester", I have below regex.

```
Pattern clubman = Pattern.compile("Manchester.*");
Matcher matche = clubman.matcher(fileString);
        if (matche.find()) {

            System.out.println("Manchester club is :"
                    + matche.group(0));
        }
```

However I need to match only the first line matching the regex i.e. `Manchester United`.
But `Pattern.compile` is finding the last match i.e. `Manchester City`.

How do I get only the first line that matches the regex.?

Comment: matching lines starting with a string does not require a regex.

Comment: Sorry , but this data is just for representational purposes. I work on confidential data so cannot post it here. 

My basic question was to get only the first line matching the pattern not the last line.

Comment: regardless, matching lines starting with a string does not require a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for this. There is no reason for it and it just makes your problem harder than it needs to be. Just loop through each line in the file and do something like

```
string match = "Manchester";
if (line.length() >= match.length()) {
  if (line.substring(0, match.length()).equals(match)) {
    return line;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , but this data is just for representational purposes. I work on confidential data so cannot post it here. My basic question was to get only the first line matching the pattern not the last line.

Comment: @CS_noob that's fine. my answer is the same. loop through each line, check for a match, and if it matches, return the line. if you have to use a regex to check for the match, go for it. it will have much better performance to go line by line anyway, since the entire file does not need to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is a match you should use 
[groupCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()).
You are using [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) which finds the next match, thus the program will print the second match.